# "mate sample.js" command not working from Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, textmate

I tried creating a new js file from the mac terminal (i.e., mate sample.js) but got the below  error:

> -bash: mate: command not found

I'm not sure how to create a new file directly from the Terminal. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Surely you can think of some other ways to create a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create and open a file with TextMate. For that to work, you have to meet two conditions:

1. Having TextMate installed
2. Having TextMate's command-line tool (`mate`) installed (in TM 2.0, you can do that from Preferences > Terminal tab)

Answer (score 3):

```
touch someFile.js
```

or

```
vim someFile.js
```

or

```
nano someFile.js
```

or

```
cp someOtherFIle.js someFile.js
```

EDIT:

Vim commands help:

http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html